# How to use GeoStyling["OutlineMap"] as GeoBackground for GeoHistogram?

Tags: geography, geographics

Say I have some location data.

```
SeedRandom[123]
locs = GeoPosition[
  Reverse[RandomPoint[Rectangle[{-88.6273, 29.6616}, {-84.2036, 32.7994}], 400], 2]]
```

I want to create a fully interactive `GeoHistogram` (with tooltips and other additions still functioning) but with a `GeoStyling["OutlineMap"]` specification for the states/provencies (`EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "ADM2"]`) within the `GeoBounds` of the data (plus any `GeoPadding`).

Unfortunately it appears that `GeoBackground` cannot be used as you cannot specify the geo-polygons directly or with an `"AdministrativeDivision"` class.

```
GeoHistogram[locs,
 GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[2, "AngularDegrees"],
 GeoBackground -> {GeoStyling["OutlineMap", 
    Directive[Lighter[LightGray, .25], EdgeForm[LightYellow]]], 
   EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "ADM2"]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can however, create the backround and the histrogram separately and use `Show` but this appears to be broken.

With the map background you have to know what areas you are in since simply specifying `EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "ADM2"]["Polygon"]` starts the download of ten's of thousand's of polygons.

```
map =
 GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["OutlineMap", 
    Directive[Lighter[LightGray, .25], EdgeForm[LightYellow]]], 
   EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "ContinentalUSStates"]["Polygon"]},
  GeoBackground -> Lighter[LightBlue, .25],
  GeoRange -> GeoBounds[locs],
  GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[2, "AngularDegrees"]
  ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Creating an none background for a `GeoHistogram` is easy enough.

```
geoHist = 
 GeoHistogram[locs, GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[2, "AngularDegrees"], 
  GeoBackground -> None]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

However it appears that `Show` does not work with `GeoGraphics`.  It completely ignores the `GeoBounds` option.  However, interactivity is preserved.

```
Show[map, geoHist]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`Overlay` works but kills the interactivity.  Tooltips and other added functionality do not work.

```
Overlay[{map, geoHist}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Therefore, I would like to know if there are some hidded options/features for `GeoHistogram` that will preserve interactivity while allowing a `GeoStyling["OutlineMap"]` specification at an `"AdministrativeDivision"` class level (`"ADM1"`, `"ADM2"`, or `"ADM3"`) without having to `EntityPrefetch` all `"AdministrativeDivision"` `"Polygon"`s available. Any ideas? Also, confirmation on the apparent `Show` bug.

Mma 11.3.0 on Win 10 Ent

Comment: Side note first, by setting the second layer as the active one you can preserve tooltips etc: `Overlay[{map, geoHist}, All, 2]` I'm not sure about geo options (and don't want to investigate) but if you repeat relevant ones in `Show` it looks ok too: `Show[map, geoHist , GeoRange -> GeoBounds[locs] , GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[2, "AngularDegrees"] ]`

Comment: This was an answer but I realized it does not address the question :)

Comment: @Kuba This `Show` and `Overlay` clarification is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this line at the `Show` statement...

```
Show[map, geoHist, GeoRange -> OptionValue[Options[geoHist], GeoRange]]
```